# Does the browser consult the cache automatically, if I put some files in the cache using Cache API?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, service-worker, cacheapi

If I put a file in the cache using the Cache API - from the main page, without a Service Worker - will the browser consult the cache automatically, if the request/url I use in cache.put() matches the new/subsequent request?
Or is it always necessary to use the Service Worker, if you want to serve the files that you had previously put into the cache?

Comment: You can have the same request used in different caches at the same time, how would the browser know which of these use? The Cache API is for your code, and if you don't grab the responses from it, the browser won't either.